# Java - No enclosing instance of the type ... is accessible in scope

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
public class PetAssembly extends Global
{
    public Socket socket;
    public ConnectionManager user;

    public PetAssembly(Socket socket, ConnectionManager user)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void initPet()
    {
        sendPacket(socket, "0|PET|I|0|0|1");
        sendPacket(socket, "0|PET|S|1000|1|0|8000|50000|50000|1000|1000|50000|50000|" + (((user.user.getSpeed() * 30) / 100) + user.user.getSpeed()) + "|testPet");
    }
}
```

I want to use it:

```
case "/pet":
      PetAssembly.this.initPet();
break;
```

But it gives me this error, how to fix it? I'm a beginner : `No enclosing instance of the type PetAssembly is accessible in scope`

Comment: `new PetAssembly().initPet()` ?

Comment: initPet() is an instance method, so you need to have an instance of the PetAssembly class in order to use the method. You can either make the initPet method static (which will require sendPacket method to be static also) or you could create an instance of your class in the case statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PetAssembly.initPet() is an instance method.  You first need to construct an object of PetAssembly (an instance of that class), and then have a reference to that object before you can invoke a method on it.

```
PetAssembly pa = new PetAssembly(socket, user); 
// Creates a new PetAssembly object
// and stores a reference to that in the variable pa.
pa.initPet(); 
// Calls the initPet() method on the PetAssembly object referred to by the variable pa.
```